# Using Steamworks.NET on Unity Editor always return game ID 480 even if I change the steam_appid.txt file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I trying to use Steamworks.NET in my Steam game that is already published.

I download the unitypackage from Steamworks from the site below
https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET/releases

This is the code that I use:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Steamworks;

public class init : MonoBehaviour {

    CGameID m_GameID;
    void Start(){
        if(SteamManager.Initialized) {
            string name = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();
            Debug.Log(name);

            // Cache the GameID for use in the Callbacks
            m_GameID = new CGameID(SteamUtils.GetAppID());
            Debug.Log ("gameID: "+m_GameID);

            Debug.Log ("achi: "+SteamUserStats.GetNumAchievements ());

        }

    }

}
```

But for some reason the game always return the game ID 480 (from Spacewar), check the image below

[image: Image from Unity]

I put my game id inside steam_appid.txt and change the code inside SteamManager

from

if (SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary(AppId_t.Invalid)) {

to

if (SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary((AppId_t)711930)) {

But still don't understand why I still get the app id from SpaceWars.

How I can correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I export a build and use the steam_appid.txt to identify my game. This way I was able to test the achievements with Steamworks.NET on my game.